# Describe those lines

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>    

#define get(s) #s  //***

int main()
{
    char str[] = get(hello);  //***

    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Help me to understand the two lines with the `//***` comment?
Can anyone describe what's happening in the `#define`?

Comment: Here's a similar example with explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_stringification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using the preprocessor's **stringification** feature.  You can read more about it at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace under "# and ## operators".

The effect is that the second marked line expands to

```
    char str[] = "hello";
```